# Error Analysis in ANN (modeling)

Tags: error, model, numerics

I am using Artificial Neural Networks (FFBP, RBF, GRN) and Multi Linear Regression techniques to model a real world case study.

I have a small list of records (60 data items). 
I am using 48 of 60 as my training data set and the remaining 12 as my testing data set.

I have two diagrams: one is based on actual observations for my test set (49 to 60), the other diagram is based on the estimations from the models for my test set (49 to 60).

I have three questions:

1. What is the best error range for this models (short record data)?
2. How can I calculate the error amount that can be added and subtracted with observation to form the error range?
3. What is the level of confidence?

I would appreciate if you can direct me to similar examples (or some tutorial) where I can learn to find the answers to my questions.

[image]